# Using Spring Scheduled Annotation and Update View

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a question about how to correctly use Spring's Scheduled annotation effectively. Basically I want to do the following; I have a web application and plan on updating a map every 30 minutes with the most recent\fresh data then saving to cache. I am using Spring already for my website so I figured this annotation would be a good fit to use and it would be easy but I am a little confused how to appropriately have this scheduled method called. I understand that creating there's a step of creating an Interface\Service and using that but after you're all done with running your behind the scenes task, how does this updated info return to the View? In this sense, my app would update the map...

I've used regular Async tasks before in Java and with the Android framework where data is processed on another thread, then is accessible\or return in an internal method but I am struggling to find a way to have my method kicked off automatically but also get the data back to the view. I've read over the Spring documentation and looked at various tutorials but am missing some disconnect. Almost all examples using the Scheduled annotation after printed to console which kind of meanders around my central question. How do I get data from this automatically run function back to my View? Below is the very limited code I have is below.

Any help would greatly be appreciated in explaining how this works. I feel once I "get it" or understand how to do this it won't actually be hard at all. Just having trouble wrapping my head around it.

```
public class CallDBSteps {

    @Scheduled(cron="*/2 * * * * MON-FRI")
    public void updateMapItems(){
        System.out.println("Started cron job");
        /**
         * Call method 1
         * Call method 2
         * Call method 3
         * Return how? return to view, what?
         */

    }
}
```

Comment: How about just having a `public static` datastructure/variable that can be updated by `updateMapItems` and read by whatever clients

Comment: Hmmmm, I guess technically that would work. I didn't really think of that option, and definitely not opposed to it. So basically I call the methods I need and once I'm done, assign the result to the static variable. Once this happens, I assume I could call a method where I could add the static variable and return to the View?

Answer (score 1):

To send data from server to client at interval of 30 min the connection between browser and server has to be maintained(connection-open) , which is not the case when we make http request. So to send anything from server to client on certain interval only if both r connected, webSocket.io provides solution for this.
However In your case I think polling (ajax calls) will suit the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If your web is based on Http/1.1,you could poll the serve for the fresh data with ajax.Otherwise,update Http/1.1 to Http/2.0 or Web Socket.